# select multiple="multiple" how to check some indexes

Tags: jquery

I have this select

```
<select id="test" multiple="multiple">
<option value="a">Test 1</option>
<option value="b">Test 2</option>
<option value="c">Test 3</option>
<option value="d">Test 4</option>
</select>
```

I have an Array ["a","c"] and what to select this values on the component.
Tried

```
$("#test").val(["a","c"])
```

but it doen't work, what's the best way?

Tks

Comment: What you have should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/aU4Yk/1/

Comment: you're correct @JamesAllardice

Answer (score 0):

You have done is correct although you can
Try this:

```
 var array1=["a","c"];
$.each(array1,function(index, value){

              $('#test option[value="'+value+'"]').attr("selected",true);
           });
```

Answer (score -1):

Imagine you have a button to trigger this you can do:

```
$("input#yourbutton").click(function() {  
     //Deselect all items
     $("#test").each(function() {  
         $("#test option").removeAttr("selected");  
     }); 

     //Cycle through all options and select it if its value is in your_array
     $("#test").each(function() {  
         if ($.inArray($(this).val(), your_array))
             $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
     }); 
});
```

Comment: You should not use `$('#test').each()` and you could also replace usage of `removeAttr()` and `attr()` with `.prop('selected', true/false)`.